# Flyway not finding migrations when run from IntelliJ when using Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

When I run my Spring Boot Kotlin application that uses Flyway from the command line, it seems to work, but from IntelliJ it fails. I created a minimal sample project that replicates the problem: https://github.com/pupeno/notflying

The error I get from IntelliJ is about the migrations not being found:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migrations or check your Flyway configuration)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.checkLocationExists(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:184) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.flyway(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:149) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ffc78d0a.CGLIB$flyway$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ffc78d0a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5b3da70f.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ffc78d0a.flyway(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

The migrations are there and correctly named as far as I can see:

```
PS C:\Users\pupeno\Temporary\notflying> dir .\src\main\resources\db\migration\


    Directory: C:\Users\pupeno\Temporary\notflying\src\main\resources\db\migration


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2019-08-26     08:32            718 V0001__create_countries_table.sql


PS C:\Users\pupeno\Temporary\notflying>
```

The IntelliJ configuration for running it looks like this:

[image]

I added:

```
logging.level.org.flywaydb=DEBUG
```

to `application.properties` and the full output of trying to start the application from IntelliJ looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\jbr\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=50536:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\pupeno\Temporary\notflying\build\classes\java\main;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.1.7.RELEASE\5e4a5d5442f32f5e12b36674a620ec57b0b66c6e\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\2.1.7.RELEASE\cf9547e20aa6a32c0b0f53400db6eecfab660f86\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.1.7.RELEASE\fa43baf40bde3ecdb93ac9c545dd39f82ab29c35\spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.module\jackson-module-kotlin\2.9.9\446b0567b26965cf7db859ba48a73ab30b4016b7\jackson-module-kotlin-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.1.7.RELEASE\5a846c6e9ab67a4cbf7c4f22bc13bcab188198f9\spring-boot-devtools-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.flywaydb\flyway-core\5.2.4\50a92d39554615bd4ff56d148a359b20dc17f655\flyway-core-5.2.4.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.2.71\7512db3b3182753bd2e48ce8d345abbadc40fe6b\kotlin-reflect-1.2.71.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8\1.2.71\5470d1f752cd342edb77e1062bac07e838d2cea4\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.2.71.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.1.7.RELEASE\4577d056af1f823bb7730c99f43c3268dd697310\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.1.7.RELEASE\3ea97a134b44a886ff529215e7bec04bfd93fa5b\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.3\e006adf5cf3cca2181d16bd640ecb80148ec0fce\javax.transaction-api-1.3.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.xml.bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\8531ad5ac454cc2deb9d4d32c40c4d7451939b5d\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.h2database\h2\1.4.199\7bf08152984ed8859740ae3f97fae6c72771ae45\h2-1.4.199.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate\hibernate-core\5.3.10.Final\e608b854325005edbf43cb2b6041fdafd3f2eb57\hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-jpa\2.1.10.RELEASE\12639406aa28c3a5195a1a4c9077fe562f54bc31\spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aspects\5.1.9.RELEASE\a8aec853c345ed54a99627cee9f755ce7dbb734\spring-aspects-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.1.7.RELEASE\9c12f046a7c4ae110d89163a491ad0d7cf036e79\spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.7.RELEASE\e23f4e9460e0e2220b444e40fc7fd6e95f66e0fe\spring-boot-starter-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring5\3.0.11.RELEASE\de7bf0adf13b5e9c4811f95edf18279da193c0c6\thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.thymeleaf.extras\thymeleaf-extras-java8time\3.0.4.RELEASE\36e7175ddce36c486fff4578b5af7bb32f54f5df\thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.1.7.RELEASE\11f2a86aefefba72a4efe5ff18f4165a4b4e78b\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.17.Final\af73055fc4a103ab347c56e7da5a143d68a0170\hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-webmvc\5.1.9.RELEASE\b9d4a2140488f0e6f9aa231e7938ae18da77b637\spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-web\5.1.9.RELEASE\9fe4390420fdd0b63dc4ed90d9027dafa9f74f80\spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.9\4b04126963103216c9c43b0f34bbc36315654204\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.9\a33df137557793b0404a486888dbe049f7abeeeb\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.9\a92facb55a2538e7b2fe14294570a18b823ad431\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.9.9\d6eb9817d9c7289a91f043ac5ee02a6b3cc86238\jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\7c10d545325e3a6e72e06381afe469fd40eb701\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.2.71\4ce93f539e2133f172f1167291a911f83400a5d0\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.71.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.2.71\d9717625bb3c731561251f8dd2c67a1011d6764c\kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.7.RELEASE\2c9d3e2c6ea3cb435e99e2973009636b62a9d816\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot\2.1.7.RELEASE\1599a2ad1fc6d36dbfc2a7c0dd5dab3a0bb27c61\spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-context\5.1.9.RELEASE\c37f8fe15a5ae4ea1f351bd46167fd492a84eefa\spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aop\5.1.9.RELEASE\bc2312ffad02251b9d472e4a7c0e472a58f50fbf\spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.4\9205229878f3d62fbd3a32a0fb6be2d6ad8589a9\aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.zaxxer\HikariCP\3.2.0\6c66db1c636ee90beb4c65fe34abd8ba9396bca6\HikariCP-3.2.0.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-orm\5.1.9.RELEASE\220169d217f7114706141fc0afba425a5b368dce\spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jdbc\5.1.9.RELEASE\3fd70356ba8d7c00c4081c1a207766352624414e\spring-jdbc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\85262acf3ca9816f9537ca47d5adeabaead7cb16\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.4.Final\965a18fdf939ee75e41f7918532d37b3a8350535\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss.logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\3789d00e859632e6c6206adc0c71625559e6e3b0\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\25665ac8c0b62f50e6488173233239120fc52c96\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.javassist\javassist\3.23.2-GA\c5afe660a95e87ceb518e4f5cf02f5c56b547683\javassist-3.23.2-GA.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.9.16\e7d63009be7b87ff1f15b72e5b8c59c897a8d8bd\byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss\jandex\2.0.5.Final\7060f67764565b9ee9d467e3ed0cb8a9c601b23a\jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml\classmate\1.4.0\291658ac2ce2476256c7115943652c0accb5c857\classmate-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.dom4j\dom4j\2.1.1\3dce5dbb3571aa820c677fadd8349bfa8f00c199\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-commons\2.1.10.RELEASE\c73a76070181b59b19df6893e1ca729263a69b47\spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-tx\5.1.9.RELEASE\a9125e2c8eeb193030f3972c6293616943c55ef2\spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-beans\5.1.9.RELEASE\5a03b3983108d73978aec2fa3e681aedad6782c\spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-expression\5.1.9.RELEASE\db3a2468c1b7d697ec3b3ec6e5652dc282994fe3\spring-expression-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-core\5.1.9.RELEASE\dc3815439579b4fa0c19970e6b8e5d774af8d988\spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.0.11.RELEASE\628ebb91f520053d4120b7b18bf78ff295d57461\thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.1.7.RELEASE\6e829f739992a7f368c0af44a08ed89ad2a1972f\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.2\6d37bf7b046c0ce2669f26b99365a2cfa45c4c18\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.26\8031352b2bb0a49e67818bf04c027aa92e645d5c\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.26\77100a62c2e6f04b53977b9f541044d7d722693d\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\934c04d3cfef185a8008e7bf34331b79730a9d43\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.22\45974d3443cc15ad9d10239d762d5e15759e6364\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.22.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.22\79f39903498b28adacb18fe2ea046edd306295a6\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.22\4da4b778b635a7e78ca7cd7288253e2e47b88a9f\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.22.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\cb855558e6271b1b32e716d24cb85c7f583ce09e\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.9.9\bfff5af9fb8347d26bbb7959cb9b4fe9a2b0ca5e\jackson-core-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.2.71\ba18ca1aa0e40eb6f1865b324af2f4cbb691c1ec\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.2.71.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\ec62d74fe50689c28c0ff5b35d3aebcaa8b5be68\snakeyaml-1.23.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.9.RELEASE\7c372790c999777d20f364960cf557dd74f890cf\spring-jcl-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.attoparser\attoparser\2.0.5.RELEASE\a93ad36df9560de3a5312c1d14f69d938099fa64\attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.unbescape\unbescape\1.1.6.RELEASE\7b90360afb2b860e09e8347112800d12c12b2a13\unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-core\1.2.3\864344400c3d4d92dfeb0a305dc87d953677c03c\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api\2.11.2\f5e9a2ffca496057d6891a3de65128efc636e26e\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar tech.flexpoint.notflying.NotflyingApplicationKt

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.7.RELEASE)

2019-08-26 10:36:00.478  INFO 7132 --- [  restartedMain] t.f.notflying.NotflyingApplicationKt     : Starting NotflyingApplicationKt on Utopia-Planitia with PID 7132 (C:\Users\pupeno\Temporary\notflying\build\classes\java\main started by pupeno in C:\Users\pupeno\Temporary\notflying)
2019-08-26 10:36:00.484  INFO 7132 --- [  restartedMain] t.f.notflying.NotflyingApplicationKt     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-26 10:36:00.549  INFO 7132 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-08-26 10:36:00.550  INFO 7132 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-08-26 10:36:01.616  INFO 7132 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-08-26 10:36:01.641  INFO 7132 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 16ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-08-26 10:36:02.113  INFO 7132 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e16cf649] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-08-26 10:36:02.433  INFO 7132 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-08-26 10:36:02.460  INFO 7132 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-08-26 10:36:02.460  INFO 7132 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.22]
2019-08-26 10:36:02.696  INFO 7132 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-08-26 10:36:02.696  INFO 7132 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2146 ms
2019-08-26 10:36:02.831  WARN 7132 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migrations or check your Flyway configuration)
2019-08-26 10:36:02.834  INFO 7132 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-08-26 10:36:02.848  INFO 7132 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-08-26 10:36:02.864 ERROR 7132 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migrations or check your Flyway configuration)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at tech.flexpoint.notflying.NotflyingApplicationKt.main(NotflyingApplication.kt:13) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migrations or check your Flyway configuration)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migrations or check your Flyway configuration)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.checkLocationExists(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:184) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.flyway(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:149) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$616ac3e9.CGLIB$flyway$1(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$616ac3e9$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a2f39a48.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$616ac3e9.flyway(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've tried this, with the same result, both with the JDK provided by IntelliJ (version 11 I think) as well as Oracle JDK 11:

```
PS C:\Users\pupeno\Temporary\notflying> java --version
java 12.0.2 2019-07-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

When I trigger a build in IntelliJ, I get some warning (not sure if relevant):

[image]

I re-created the project with Maven and it seems to work out of the box, with no issues. So, I'd say, the problem seems to be in how IntelliJ imports Gradle projects.

Comment: please try to create a folder in  `db/` called `migrations` in plural.

Comment: @JonathanJohx: that gives me the same error.

Comment: Ok then try to add this setting to change the location `spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migrations` add a folder called `migrations`

Comment: And put your sql files in `db/migrations` folder @pupeno

Comment: Why migrations instead of migration? At any rate, that still gives me the same error.

Comment: the same error? so you can't change the location? I mean if the error say: `db/migrations` now

Comment: The error still say "db/migration", even after adding `spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migrations` to application.properties.

Comment: OK, what happen if you put `spring.flyway.locations=classpath:/db/migrations` adding an `/` slash at the beginning

Comment: May be point it to a new DB and see if it changes anything?

Comment: suppose this is due to the gradle, can you try to execute "Reimport gradle project" from Gradle panel?

Comment: @LipingHuang: I've tried reimporting it a few times, to no effect. :(

Comment: I just recreated the project using Maven and it works. Maybe IntelliJ Gradle-import doesn't work as well?

Comment: @pupeno Actually I checked your project which is used the latest gradle ( rewriting with kotlin) and seems intellij IDEA not sync the project well, but anyway, glad to hear it works now, congratulation.

Comment: For my project, I might just use Maven, but I'm sure other people might feel strongly about using Gradle and want a proper answer to this.

Answer (score 5):

Perfectly work on my machine

Probably migrations not copied to `build/resources/main/db` directory

Try next:

1. Delete `build` directory
2. Invalidate idea cache [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/cleaning-system-cache.html)
3. Reimport gradle [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24813490/6066470)

If that doesn't help replace `Build` to `gradle build` in configuration settings:
[image]

Also maybe gradle not have access to read migration file or parent directory. Check permissions in file system or try clone github repository to another folder.

Comment: You are correct that migrations are not copied, but performing these steps didn't do it either.

Comment: @pupeno may be gradle not have permissions for read migrations. Try clone project from github to another folder

Comment: I did try the project in two different computers, with the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Intellij might have created the directory as

```
src/main/resources/db.migration
```

with the files in a directory called `db.migration`, instead of

```
src/main/resources/db/migration
```

with the files in a directory called `migration`.

Comment: The migration files are in `src/main/resources/db/migration`. `db.migration` is just a shorthand by IntelliJ. Also, it was Spring Boot initiliazr that created it.

Comment: Can you share your test project?

Comment: Sure, let me re-build it.

Comment: In your test project, it looks like your sql file only has a single underscore after the version: https://github.com/pupeno/notflying/blob/master/src/main/resources/db/migration/V0001_create_countries_table.sql it need to be a double underscore: V0001__create_countries_table.sql but in your directory listing in the question, it looks like you do have the double underscore in those files, so that might be a different problem.

Comment: Renaming `V0001_create_countries_table.sql` to `V0001__create_countries_table.sql` worked for me in the test project. The sql file was found, although the migration failed because `uuid_generate_v4()` is postgresql-specific, I believe, so not available for H2 but that's a different issue.

Comment: I don't know how that typo was inserted, but correcting it doesn't solve the problem for me. I updated the project and the question.

Answer (score 1):

My try, which succeeded:

1. Rename to a name that isn't your name in mind.
2. Run `gradle clean` and start test.
3. Expect: No migrations found.
4. Rename it again to your desired name. Run the test again.
5. Expect: Migrations found!

Its definitely a bug in IntelliJ/Gradle where it doesn't detect resources to import when there is no builds exists before its compilation. Making changes to the script refreshes its state, and automatically imports the resource afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me:

```
$ ./gradlew bootRun
./gradlew: 39: cd: can't cd to "./

> Task :bootRun

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.7.RELEASE)

2019-08-26 08:21:36.837  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] t.f.notflying.NotflyingApplicationKt     : Starting NotflyingApplicationKt on LAP025 with PID 1789 (/mnt/c/Users/bleug/Desktop/notflying/build/classes/kotlin/main started by bleug in /mnt/c/Users/bleug/Desktop/notflying)
2019-08-26 08:21:36.846  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] t.f.notflying.NotflyingApplicationKt     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-26 08:21:37.116  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-08-26 08:21:37.116  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-08-26 08:21:40.958  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-08-26 08:21:41.124  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 106ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-08-26 08:21:42.578  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6414adf5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-08-26 08:21:43.698  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-08-26 08:21:43.781  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-08-26 08:21:43.782  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.22]
2019-08-26 08:21:44.196  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-08-26 08:21:44.196  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7080 ms
2019-08-26 08:21:44.735  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 5.2.4 by Boxfuse
2019-08-26 08:21:44.765  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-08-26 08:21:45.433  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-08-26 08:21:45.460  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.c.internal.database.DatabaseFactory  : Database: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb (H2 1.4)
2019-08-26 08:21:45.607  WARN 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.c.internal.database.base.Database    : Flyway upgrade recommended: H2 1.4.199 is newer than this version of Flyway and support has not been tested.
2019-08-26 08:21:45.860  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.086s)
2019-08-26 08:21:45.893  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory         : Creating Schema History table: "PUBLIC"."flyway_schema_history"
2019-08-26 08:21:45.976  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "PUBLIC": << Empty Schema >>
2019-08-26 08:21:45.993  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 0001 - create countries table
2019-08-26 08:21:46.051  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Successfully applied 1 migration to schema "PUBLIC" (execution time 00:00.165s)
2019-08-26 08:21:46.616  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
2019-08-26 08:21:46.939  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2019-08-26 08:21:46.944  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-08-26 08:21:47.555  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-08-26 08:21:48.169  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2019-08-26 08:21:48.963  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-08-26 08:21:49.033  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2019-08-26 08:21:49.920  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-08-26 08:21:50.137  WARN 1789 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-08-26 08:21:50.476  WARN 1789 --- [  restartedMain] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2019-08-26 08:21:51.143  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-08-26 08:21:51.153  INFO 1789 --- [  restartedMain] t.f.notflying.NotflyingApplicationKt     : Started NotflyingApplicationKt in 15.774 seconds (JVM running for 17.982)
```

If you enable debug logger by adding this line in `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.flywaydb=DEBUG
```

It will show you the exact path :

```
2019-08-26 08:30:31.661 DEBUG 1996 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.c.i.s.classpath.ClassPathScanner     : Scanning URL: file:/mnt/c/Users/bleug/Desktop/notflying/build/resources/main/db/migration
```

Try to run it from a path with no space.

Edit:

Use gradle to run the project

[image]

Comment: Your answer made it clear that the problem was IntelliJ and not the migrations themselves, so, I re-wrote the question to highlight that fact. I also got rid of paths with spaces and other issues and focused on the minimal example I created.

Comment: I added `logging.level.org.flywaydb=DEBUG` but at least when running from IntelliJ, I don't get that "DEBUG" line with the path (that would help a lot).

Comment: Which version of java are you using ? https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2061#issuecomment-416046343

Comment: I installed OracleJDK (12.0.2 2019-07-16) for the command line. IntelliJ is using whatever IntelliJ comes with. Let me explore that.

Comment: Ha! You just linked to a bug I reported. This is about to get really embarrassing. :)

Comment: I switched IntelliJ to that same version of JDK and it's still failing.

Comment: FYI I used java version "1.8.0_201"

Comment: I guess I will use gradle if I can't get IntelliJ's Spring Boot support to work.

Comment: Yes, it's better anyway, closer to cli/CI.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a long shot but still:
Can you try editing the path provided to flyway scripts to use backslash instead of forward slash?

```
flyway.locations=classpath:db\migration
```

or even

```
flyway.locations=filesystem=C:\Users\pupeno\Temporary\notflying\src\main\resources\db\migration
```

I've noticed that you are running your application in a Windows environment. It might be that Gradle does some magic regarding the default values but IntelliJ doesn't.

Comment: `flyway.locations` was deprecated in favor of `spring.flyway.locations`. I tried both options and it didn't work (even after correcting the backslash escape). I'm not sure gradle is invoked when you run a Spring Boot application in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Nick was correct that migrations weren't being copied into the `build/resources` folder.

I work around this by adding the following to my script:

```groovy
tasks.withType(org.flywaydb.gradle.task.AbstractFlywayTask) {
  dependsOn processResources
}
```

Not sure why the Flyway gradle plugin doesn't do that.